# Dual vector space, proof of inclusion in a span

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** 
V is a vector space (of finite dimension) over F. We assume $\alpha, \beta \in V^*$  (The dual space) and they satisfy: $\forall v: (\alpha (v)=0 \Rightarrow \beta (v)=0$)
prove that $\beta \in sp(\alpha)$.

**What I thought:**
What I understand is that I need to prove that $\beta$ is actually $\alpha$ multiplied by a scalar. I also think that $\operatorname{Ker}\alpha \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}\beta$ (from what we were given). 
Would love some hints at first.

Comment: Does  the nullspace mean the kernel ?

Comment: Is $F$ any field or are we supposing $F=\mathbb{R}$ or $F=\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: nothing said about it in the paper, but i think you can assume R or C. we havent spoken of others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hypothesis is indeed $\ker(\alpha) \subseteq \ker(\beta)$.

There are two possibilities. Either $\beta = 0$, and then...

Otherwise $\beta \ne 0$. Then the kernels of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two subspaces of the same dimension, one contained in the other, and then...

Finally, extend a basis of $\ker(\alpha)$ to a basis of $V$, and see how $\alpha$ and $\beta$ act on this basis.

Comment: why are they of the same dimension? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: @user1685224, if $0 \ne \alpha \in V^{\star}$, since the image of $\alpha$ has dimension $1$, then $\dim(\ker(\alpha)) = n - 1$, if $n = \dim(V)$. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra)#Linear_maps)